# Google App Engine sending mails on daily basis

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I want to send mails on daily basis at 00:00 am using task queue, i can store a mail in a queue for 30 days at most. Now to make a task queue run do i need a corn job for it. Or the app engine will itself make the task run by itself.

And can i add a particular time for task queue to run like the corn job.

Comment: Could you try and be more clear on what exactly do you want to accomplish? Also what language/runtime are you working with?

Comment: I want to send mails later on a specified time.  I am using Python

Answer (score 2):

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.
>   These tasks are commonly known as cron jobs. These cron jobs are
>   automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service. For instance,
>   you might use this to send out a report email on a daily basis, to
>   update some cached data every 10 minutes, or to update some summary
>   information once an hour.
>
> A cron.yaml file in the root directory of your application (alongside
>   app.yaml) configures scheduled tasks for your Python application. The
>   following is an example cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  schedule: every 24 hours
- description: monday morning mailout
  url: /mail/weekly
  schedule: every monday 09:00
  timezone: Australia/NSW
- description: new daily summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  schedule: every 24 hours
  target: beta
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron